# Passing object from View.py to Template.html with Django

Tags: django

I am building my first application with Django, and I would like to add model object to a template.
in the views.py I have :

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def pages(request):

    context = {}
    # All resource paths end in .html.
    # Pick out the html file name from the url. And load that template.
    try:

        load_template = request.path.split('/')[-1]
        html_template = loader.get_template( load_template )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:

        html_template = loader.get_template( 'error-404.html' )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

    except:

        html_template = loader.get_template( 'error-500.html' )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))


def restricted_list(request):
    restrictednames = Restrictednames.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')

    return render(request, '/restricted_list.html', {'restrictednames': restrictednames})
```

the object i am looking to pass through is `restrictednames`.
in the template I have :

```
<body>
{{ restrictednames }} 
</body>
```

But nothing shows up. The page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/restricted_list.html` does not seem to be loading using `def restricted_list(request)` function.

The routes are as below

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Matches any html file - to be used for gentella
    # Avoid using your .html in your resources.
    # Or create a separate django app.
    re_path(r'^.*\.html', views.pages, name='pages'),

    # The home page
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('', views.restricted_list, name='restricted_list'),
]
```

I am sure this is fairly simple, but not familiar with the Django structure yet.
Does anyone sees what I am not doing right please ?

Comment: Hi, django uses a urls.py that connects the views.py methods to the browsers' request. can you share your urls.py ?

Comment: Hey @MichaelLindsay, i just edited the post and added the routes.

Answer (score 0):

Move the restricted_list url above the catchall `pages` url

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('/restricted_list.html', views.restricted_list, name='restricted_list'),

    # Matches any html file - to be used for gentella
    # Avoid using your .html in your resources.
    # Or create a separate django app.
    re_path(r'^.*\.html', views.pages, name='pages'),

    # The home page
    path('', views.index, name='home'),

]
```

Another option would be to change the url to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/restricted_list/`

Comment: Hey, I just did as per your suggestion, and the page still loads without the variable content.  Do you see something else I could try ?

Comment: I would double check to make sure that the restrictednames has data in it.  `print(restrictednames)` inside the view